# ErrorException: Undefined array key 1 in Laravel Application while fetching data from Facebook

Tags: php, laravel, facebook-graph-api

Here is my method:

```
public function getPagePosts()
{
    $fb = new Facebook([
        'app_id' => config('services.facebook.app_id'),
        'app_secret' => config('services.facebook.app_secret'),
        'default_graph_version' => 'v17.0',
    ]);

    $accessToken = config('services.facebook.default_access_token');
    $pageId = 'my_page_id'; // Replace with your page ID

    $response = $fb->get("/$pageId/posts", $accessToken);

    try {
        $response = $fb->get("/$pageId/posts", $accessToken);
        $graphEdge = $response->getGraphEdge();
        $posts = $graphEdge->asArray();

        return view('posts', ['posts' => $posts]);
    } catch (\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        // Handle any errors
        echo $e->getMessage(); // Output the error message for debugging
        // You can also log the error or redirect to an error page
    }
}
```

Got error: Undefined array key 1

Errors are on the following line:

[Output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DD2ob.jpg)

I'm trying to fetching data from my facebook pages. But it isn't giving me the response.

Comment: Your screenshot has this line hightlighted, `$response = $fb->get("/$pageId/posts", $accessToken);` - but there is no actual array access on that line. (Which you have in there twice, btw. - purpose?) You might need to follow the stack trace a bite more here, to see where it actually goes wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Library you used for integration with the facebook is outdated and is not maintained anymore on github issues you can find similar issue https://github.com/facebookarchive/php-graph-sdk/issues/1246

On packagist you can see that last release of that package were on 2018 https://packagist.org/packages/facebook/graph-sdk

You probably should search maintained package or some kind of fork.